# Getting two javascripts working on the same page

Tags: javascript

I found a script along with some HTML that counts the amount of characters you type into a box:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function change (el) {
        var max_len = 50;

        if (el.value.length > max_len) {
            el.value = el.value.substr(0, max_len);
        }

        document.getElementById('char_cnt').innerHTML = el.value.length;
        document.getElementById('chars_left').innerHTML = max_len - el.value.length;

        return true;
    }
</script>`

<form>
    <textarea style="border: 1px solid #eb008b;" cols=100 rows=2 
onkeyup="change(this);"></textarea>
    <p>You've typed <span id="char_cnt">0</span> character(s)</p>
    <p>You are allowed <span id="chars_left">lots</span> more</p>
</form>
```

In this example, it counts up to 50 characters.

I want to add a second form on the same page that counts up to 200 characters. When I duplicate the code it stops one script working.

How do I add it so both scripts work on the same page?

Comment: Show the version that isn't working

Comment: Duplicate which code?  The HTML for the `<form>`?  You're probably duplicating `id`s.  Don't do that.

Comment: I duplicated both the javascripot and the html. Changing ID's didnt work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why exactly are you setting up a second JS function?
You could easily determine which form is getting worked in when you trigger them by `id` or `name` attribute.

Try something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function change (el) {
    if (el.value.length > el.maxLength) {
      el.value = el.value.substr(0, el.maxLength);
    }
    document.getElementById(el.name + '_char_cnt').innerHTML = el.value.length;
    document.getElementById(el.name + '_chars_left').innerHTML = el.maxLength - el.value.length;
    return true;
  }
</script>

<form>
    <!-- Left Textarea -->
    <textarea name="left" style="border: 1px solid #eb008b;" cols=100 rows=2 maxLength=50 onkeyup="change(this);"></textarea>
    <p>You've typed <span id="left_char_cnt">0</span> character(s)</p>
    <p>You are allowed <span id="left_chars_left">lots</span> more</p>

    <!-- Right Textarea -->
    <textarea name="right" style="border: 1px solid #eb008b;" cols=100 rows=2 maxLength=200 onkeyup="change(this);"></textarea>
    <p>You've typed <span id="right_char_cnt">0</span> character(s)</p>
    <p>You are allowed <span id="right_chars_left">lots</span> more</p>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perfect! Worked a treat. Thanks.

Comment: You could even further improve this, when you add the `maxLength` attribute to your textareas.
So just add the attribute `maxLength=50` to the left textarea and `maxLength=200` to the right one.
Then you can access `el.maxLength` inside your script.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably duplicating `id` attributes when you copy your form code.  `document.getElementById()` will only get the first instance of something with the id specified.

Try something like this instead:

```js
const MAX_LEN = 50;

Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("form")).forEach(form => {
  const ta = form.querySelector("textarea"),
    cc = form.querySelector("span.char_count"),
    cl = form.querySelector("span.chars_left");

  ta.addEventListener("keydown", () => {
    if (ta.value.length > MAX_LEN) {
      ta.value = ta.value.substr(0, MAX_LEN);
    }
    cc.innerHTML = ta.value.length;
    cl.innerHTML = MAX_LEN - ta.value.length;
  });

});
```

```html
<form>
  <textarea style="border: 1px solid #eb008b;" cols=100 rows=2></textarea>
  <p>You've typed <span class="char_count">0</span> character(s)</p>
  <p>You are allowed <span class="chars_left">lots</span> more</p>
</form>
<form>
  <textarea style="border: 1px solid #eb008b;" cols=100 rows=2></textarea>
  <p>You've typed <span class="char_count">0</span> character(s)</p>
  <p>You are allowed <span class="chars_left">lots</span> more</p>
</form>
```